# Правильное склонение с глаголом "жаждет"

Tags: управление

*Жаждет абсолютную свободу и власть.*

Правильное ли склонение слов в этом предложении?
Или вернее будет написать: *Жаждет абсолютной свободы и власти*?

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: ***Жаждет абсолютной свободы и власти.***

См. у Розенталя:

> ***жаждать
>       чего* (не *что*)** *Жаждать славы... Я жажду своего обновления* (Чехов). *Мира жаждет все человечество...* (Павленко).

[**Пунктуация и управление в русском языке. Д.Э. Розенталь.**](http://upravlenie.academic.ru/467)